# Laravel + Vue : Routes on web.php / api.php

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am quite a new guy on Laravel and I have started working on a project, and I would like get some advice about the good architecture to pick.

I decided to manage my front with Vue and my backend with Laravel.

What I have started to do is to capture the routes through Laravel and sent it to my Vue routes to determines which components to load etc. And I was thinking to make "api" calls though axios into my Vue.components to retrieve the data (in JSON format) from my controller in order to display them into my view.

That's still a "web" needs.

But I am also thinking to the future API I will provide.

So what is the best option to take ?

Put some `Route::resource('model', 'Controller')` into the `web.php` file, then call those routes in my Vue.components, and put the `Route::resource('model','Controller')` into my `api.php` file ?

Thank you for your answer I don't know if I am going the right way or not.

Clément.

Comment: Those are just groups for dividing your routes into logical sections. Practically it has no meaning other than api.php has `/api/` prefixed. (web.php: `http://example.com/someroute`, api.php: `http://example.com/api/someroute`). So in your case, api calls? go with api.php.  Also, after some years in the business: I think it makes sense doing it the way you describe, and right now you are worrying  too much about doing it the right way instead of getting it done.

Comment: Thank you @ippi for your reply. Yeah I heard about the prefix and middleware add depending the file you put your routes on. But if you want to protect your API routes with Laravel Passport, how can you manage that easily in the controller depending if the API request is coming from a third-party customer or via the Vue.components ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you @ippi I had read that the 'web' group middleware was activated on the web.php routes, not the api.php routes ...

Comment: @user2917569 You're right the /api routes are stateless by default because of how the middleware is set up

Comment: I have just one more question, about the "Consuming Your API With JavaScript" part on the laravel documentation. It says that we have to put the CreateFreshApiToken on the 'web' group middleware on the Kernel.php, but our API routes will be in the 'api.php', do I miss something in here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [app\Http\Kernel.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php) you'll notice the distinction between the web and the api group.

- web - process "standard" requests - they need a session, checking
  against a user that logged in globally in the app, processing web
  requests. Web UI things
- api - process stateless API requests, will most likely always consume and return json

I usually keep the API routes in the api.php, prefix it with a version and load the controllers from the API namespace. This makes it a little more maintainable because v1 methods can be extended by a potential v2 version

```
Route::prefix('v1')->namespace('Api\V1')->group(function () {
    // ... API routes
});
```