# Web.php instead of api.php in laravel

Tags: laravel

Iam working on a laravel and vuejs project. I want to fetch authenticated user details. When I use api.php it is working fine but if I use web.php to set my route it is not working.

My code on Vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                user: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            showUser() {
                axios.get('user').then(response => {
                    this.user = response.data;
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.showUser();
        }
    }
</script>
```

My Controller looks like this in the index function

```
public function user() 
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    return response()->json($user);
}
```

And Route

```
Route::get('/user', [Usercontroller, 'user']);
```

Comment: I think this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856346/laravel-vue-routes-on-web-php-api-php

Comment: Why would you set API routes in web.php? That is why api.php is there, anyway it should work in web.php. you can see the response of the call in developers tools' network tab. that way you can see the error.

Comment: @Rwd My guess is he logs in on a web route, so the session doesn't exist in the api's auth.

Comment: Just an FYI, `axios.get('user')` will append user to the current url. To have it be an absolute url change it to be `axios.get('/user')`. That being said, why do you want this route to be in your `web.php` instead of your `api.php`?

Comment: Another problem observed is that when I try to retrieve logged in user details. Auth::user(); It's not working. No error on network> response tab on browser. It only shows html file

Comment: Look at storage/logs/laravel.log to check if there are errors. or is there anoter /user route? if it is a new route, don't forget "php artisan route:cache" to reset the route cache